# Homework problems for Isaacs' Algebra: A Graduate Course?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I am about to embark on a journey through Isaacs' Algebra: A Graduate Course.  He provides in the preface a very nice, detailed outline of what he covers while teaching his first-year graduate algebra course.  I would like to follow this outline, and it would be wonderful to actually 'take the course' as much as possible.  So my question is:

> Where, if anywhere, on the internet could I could access the homework problems assigned for Isaacs' first-year graduate algebra course?

I see that he is now retired from University of Wisconsin, Madison, and it appears that his webpage has been taken down from the school site.  A Google search did not yield anything either.  I'm hoping someone may have the homework problems from the course, or know where to find them.

I would also like to ask...

> Would it be reasonable to e-mail Professor Isaacs to ask for the set of homework problems he used?

Isaacs' book seems popular and I see that there are several questions on this site on problems from his book, so I think this could very well be of interest to multiple people who use this site.

I suppose I would also settle for a different set of problems that closely follows the outline of Isaacs' course, but understandably I'd love to have the problems he used personally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the answer to my second question (Would it be reasonable to e-mail Professor Isaacs to ask for the set of homework problems he used?) is 'yes'.

Not wanting to wait very long before starting into the book, I emailed Dr. Isaacs, kindly requesting the homework assignments he used for his course (last taught in 2008, it appears).  He emailed me 11 assignments and two exams from the first semester, and said he will send me the material from the second semester once I have completed what I have now.

Comment: Dear Alex, can you kindly share them with me?